# Grunt conditional declarations based on template/option values

Tags: jquery, node.js, jquery-mobile, gruntjs

I have these template settings in my Grunt configuration:

```
grunt.config.init({
    targetSuffix:   grunt.option("target") || "dev",

    mainTarget:     grunt.option("installTo") || _WEB_ROOT + "client",
    devTarget:      "<%= mainTarget %>-<%= targetSuffix %>",
    coverageTarget: _WEB_ROOT + "client-coverage" + ("<%= targetSuffix %>" ? "-<%= targetSuffix %>" : ""),

    // ...
});
```

The first two work without error, whether specified on the command line (`grunt install --target=user1`) or in a "shortcut" task:

```
grunt.registerTask("user1", "same as 'grunt install --target=user1'", function() {
    grunt.config.set("targetSuffix", "user1");
    // or grunt.option("target", "user1");
    grunt.task.run("install");
});
```

(It's not clear in the documentation, but I'll assume for now that `grunt.config` processing happens after `grunt.option`.)

It's the `coverageTarget` definition that is giving me problems. If no `target` is specified, I want `_WEB_ROOT + "client-coverage"`. If there is a `target`, add a hyphen then the target value. The difference from `devTarget` is that it has `mainTarget` for the unspecified state, because the two are used separately throughout my tasks.

I don't need or want to have to right separate tasks/targets to support a `coverageMainTarget` and `coverageDevTarget`. However, I can't seem to get any conditionals (ternary operator) to work in the declaration.

Here are the results for four test cases: default behavior, command-line option, `grunt.option()` and `grunt.config.set()`.

```
/*
 * "client-coverage-dev" for default and grunt.option().
 * Should be "client-coverage". Implies "<%= targetSuffix %>"
 * isn't "dev", but that's what gets appended.
 * "client-coverage-user1" for CL and grunt.config.set()
 */
coverageTarget: _WEB_ROOT + "client-coverage" + ("<%= targetSuffix %>" != "dev" ? "-<%= targetSuffix %>" : "")

/*
 * Only appends a target for CL option. All others yield
 * "client-coverage".
 */
coverageTarget: _WEB_ROOT + "client-coverage" + (grunt.option("target") ? "-<%= targetSuffix %>" : "")
// or
coverageTarget: _WEB_ROOT + "client-coverage" + (grunt.option("target") ? "-" + grunt.option("target") : "")

/*
 * All output "client-coverage".
 */
coverageTarget: _WEB_ROOT + "client-coverage" + (grunt.config.get("targetSuffix") ? "-<%= targetSuffix %>" : "")
// or
coverageTarget: _WEB_ROOT + "client-coverage" + (grunt.config.get("targetSuffix") ? "-" + grunt.config.get("targetSuffix") : "")
```

I've also tried processing outside/before `grunt.config.init`, but in that case `grunt.option()` only returns the `target` option if it's specified on the command line, *not* if set with `grunt.option()`.

How can I tell Grunt to construct a declaration based on the existence or value of another declaration or template string? Is there some Grunt dependency loop going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The Grunt option API is for sharing parameters across multiple tasks and accessing parameters set on the command line." However, to make the values easily accessible in Grunt templates*, I decided to stick with `grunt.config` instead of `grunt.option`.

I then realized I can do the processing I need outside of *and after* the call to `grunt.config.init()` (a.k.a., `grunt.initConfig()`).

```
grunt.config.init({
    // for example...
    clean: {
        options: {
            force: true
        }
        ,build:    ["client-build/", "client/extlibs/", "coverage/"]
        ,prod:     "<%= installTarget %>/**"
        ,dev:      "<%= installTarget %>/**"
        ,coverage: "<%= cvgTarget %>/**"
    }
});

// store the function so you can re-process, if needed
var processOpts = function () {
    var _WEB_ROOT = "/my/webroot/";
    var _CONTEXTS = ["prod", "dev"];
    var dev = grunt.option("dev");

    if (dev === true) { // if given just "--dev"
        grunt.config.set("installTarget", _WEB_ROOT + "client-dev");
        grunt.config.set("cvgTarget",     _WEB_ROOT + "client-coverage-dev");
        grunt.config.set("context",       "dev");
    } else if (dev !== undefined && dev !== "") { // "--dev=name"
        grunt.config.set("installTarget", _WEB_ROOT + "client-" + dev);
        grunt.config.set("cvgTarget",     _WEB_ROOT + "client-coverage-" + dev);
        grunt.config.set("context",       "dev");
    } else {
        var target = grunt.option("installTo");
        if (target === undefined || target === "") {
            grunt.config.set("installTarget", _WEB_ROOT + "client");
            grunt.config.set("cvgTarget",     _WEB_ROOT + "client-coverage");
        } else {
            grunt.config.set("installTarget", target);
        }

        var context = grunt.option("context");
        if (_CONTEXTS.indexOf(context) === -1) {
            // invalid context, default to first value ("prod")
            grunt.config.set("context", _CONTEXTS[0]);
        } else {
            grunt.config.set("context", context);
        }
    }

    grunt.verbose.writeln("installTarget: " + grunt.config.get("installTarget"));
    grunt.verbose.writeln("cvgTarget: "     + grunt.config.get("cvgTarget"));
    grunt.verbose.writeln("context: "       + grunt.config.get("context"));

    // build context-specific targets dynamically
    var i;
    var commonTasks = ["compass", "requirejs", "clean", "template", "copy", "setmymode"];
    for (i=0; i<commonTasks.length; i++) {
        commonTasks[i] += ":" + grunt.config.get("context");
    }

    grunt.registerTask("prod", ["clean:build", "bower:install", "jshint:prod", "karma:unit"].concat(commonTasks));
    grunt.registerTask("dev",  [               "bower:install"                             ].concat(commonTasks));
};
processOpts();

// main tasks for command-line
grunt.registerTask("default",  ["prod", "coverage"]);

// dev task aliases
grunt.registerTask("n13", "same as 'grunt dev --dev=n13'", function() {
    grunt.option("dev", "n13");
    processOpts();
    grunt.task.run("dev");
});
```